# Allow user to select ports for Apache Tomcat: how should HTTPS & AJP port numbers be calculated?

Tags: http, tomcat, https, port, ajp

My customer wants the ability to choose his tomcat port at install time. I'm not too familiar with tomcat but I know that there are three ports needed:

- HTTP port (usually 80 or 8080?)
- HTTPS port (usually 443 or 8443?)
- AJP port (usually 8009?)

The user will definitely be able to choose his HTTP port, but what kind of scheme or pattern should I use to calculate the HTTPS/AJP ports? Could a user be allowed to select them too, or must it be done by the programmer?

Comment: You don't need an AJP port unless there is an Apache HTTPD in front, but you also need a shutdown port. If the customer is such an expert why not let him install and configure the whole thing himself? Why get involved? Off topic.

Comment: I am writing our installer script. I also don't think they're actually experts

Comment: As EJP has pointed out: [Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This isn't a question for SO.